# If $\alpha$ is even show that $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is even.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Right then I have $\alpha,\beta \in S_n$ for some n and that $\alpha$ is even. I want to show that $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is even.

What I came up with:

I know that I can write $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the product of 2-cycles (if n > 1) and I've shown that if $\beta = \sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_n $ where each $\sigma_i$ is a 2-cycle then $\beta^{-1}$ can be written as $\beta^{-1} = \sigma_n \sigma_{n-1} ... \sigma_1$so I know that if $\beta$ is even then so is $\beta^{-1}$ and likewise for odd. So then I can say $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is a product of $\alpha$'s 2-cycles which we have an even number of and twice the number of $\beta$'s 2-cycles which gives us a second even number of 2-cycles so $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is even as desired.

Does this work alright? I think it's kinda poorly worded but I'm having trouble fixing that.

Also for $n = 1$. The only permutation in $S_1$ is the identity right? Since the identity is even it follows immediately right?

Thoughts on how to clean this up (or indeed if it is wrong please point that out) are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd want to do this by counting 2-cycles; it could get messy fast.

An easier approach: the cycle type of a permutation is a conjugacy class invariant -- this amounts to observing that conjugation in $S_n$ is just 'relabeling' the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, just like a change-of-basis matrix with vector spaces.

Alternatively, if you defined the even permutations as the kernel of the nontrivial homomorphism $S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$, you could just note that the kernel of a homomorphism is normal.

Comment: unfortunately we haven't had any of that introduced in the class and I hesitate to use it on the homework for fear of losing points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_{2m}$, then $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1} = (\beta \tau_1 \beta^{-1}) \cdots (\beta \tau_{2m}  \beta^{-1})$. Now note that $\beta \tau_i \beta^{-1}$ is also a 2-cycle. Therefore, $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is a product of an even number of 2-cycles and so is even.