# Showing that $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ and $\alpha$ both odd or even

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Question: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belong to $S_{n}$. Prove that $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ and $\alpha$ are both odd or even.

$\alpha \alpha ^{-1} =\varepsilon =\beta^{-1} \beta $
where $\varepsilon$ is an even permutation.

Let $\alpha = \sigma _{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot \sigma_{s}$, $\beta = \theta _{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot \theta_{t}$

Observe: 
$\varepsilon =\sigma _{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot \sigma_{s} \theta _{1}\cdot \cdot \cdot \theta_{t}$

Thus, s + t is even implies that both s and t are either odd or even.

$\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ has $\left ( 2t + s \right )$ 2-cycles.

A crucial piece of detail could be preventing me from completing this proof.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529195/if-alpha-is-even-show-that-beta-alpha-beta-1-is-even?rq=1 will help?

Comment: I am unable to understand how it is a product of an even number of two cycles.

Comment: The proof in the link has three sentences. Which one of those specifically do you not understand?

Comment: The second sentence. He asked to note that the composition is a 2-cycle. But I am unable to understand why that composition is a product of an even number of 2 -cycles.
It's much similar to my work above. Except that, I am unable to 'see' why it is an even number of 2 cycles

Comment: Perhaps then it would be a good idea to try some small examples. A permutation is a $2$-cycle when it interchanges precisely two elements. If $\tau$ is a $2$-cycle, what elements can the permutation $\beta \tau \beta^{-1}$ change?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if:

$\alpha = \sigma_1\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_k$

that:

$\beta\alpha\beta^{-1} = (\beta\sigma_1\beta^{-1})(\beta\sigma_2\beta^{-1})\cdots(\beta\sigma_k\beta^{-1})$.

Now if each $\sigma_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,k$ is a transposition, we will show each $\beta\sigma_i\beta^{-1}$ is likewise a transposition.

Suppose $\sigma_i = (a\ b)$. Let us denote:

$c = \beta(a)$ and $d = \beta(b)$, so that $\beta^{-1}(c) = a$, and $\beta^{-1}(d) = b$.

If $m \not\in \{c,d\}$, then $\beta^{-1}(m) \not\in \{a,b\}$ (because $\beta,\beta^{-1}$ are bijective), and thus:

$\sigma_i\beta^{-1}(m) = \sigma_i(\beta^{-1}(m)) = \beta^{-1}(m)$, since $\sigma_i$ only affects $a$ and $b$.

Therefore, $\beta\sigma_i\beta^{-1}(m) = \beta(\sigma_i(\beta^{-1}(m))) = \beta(\beta^{-1}(m)) = m$.

If $m = c$, we have: $\beta\sigma_i\beta^{-1}(c) = \beta(\sigma_i(\beta^{-1}(c))) = \beta(\sigma_i(a)) = \beta(b) = d$,

and if $m = d$, we have: $\beta\sigma_i\beta^{-1}(d) = \beta(\sigma_i(\beta^{-1}(d))) = \beta(\sigma_i(b)) = \beta(a) = c$.

So, $\beta\sigma_i\beta^{-1} = (c\ d)$.

Thus if $\alpha$ is a product of $k$ transpositions, $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ is likewise, whether $k$ be even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following homomorphism: $f:S_n \to \{-1,1\}$ given by

$$f(A_n)=1 \, \,, f(S_n\backslash A_n)=-1.$$

One should check that this is indeed a homomorphism, and that it is typically denoted $\mathrm{Sgn}$. If you check that it is a homomorphism, you can see that its kernel is exactly $A_n$, so $A_n$ is a normal subgroup which means that $\sigma A_n \sigma^{-1}=A_n$.

**edit:** Without explicit use of homomorphisms, you can use the fact that the decomposition into transpositions is *not* unique, but its parity is. Hence, we can see that if $\sigma:=\sigma_1\dots \sigma_n$, where $\sigma_i$ are transpositions and $\tau:=\tau_1\dots \tau_k$ where $\tau_j$ are transpositions, then $\sigma \tau =(\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_n)(\tau_1 \cdots \tau_k)$, which has some parity independent of its decomposition. You can use this to finish the problem ,and look [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/sign.pdf) for some more in depth discussion.

Comment: Can you do this with only permutation?

Comment: yeah, you can. I think the first way is easiest though.

Comment: How does your edited comment ties in with my current attempt? it isn't as though I haven't tried after having worked on  this for 90 mins while having also looked at the theorem related to your comments.

Comment: I already know $\beta \alpha$ is even

Comment: so what **don't** you know?

Comment: I don't know what $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is. This stems from the fact that I don't know if $\beta$ is odd or even.

Comment: Why not try the following argument: if $\beta$ is even iff $\beta^{-1}$ is even, so first suppose that $\beta$ is even, and then odd. It will not change your proof at all.  Ultimately it will not matter: $\beta \tau \beta^{-1}$ is *always* odd when $\tau$ is a transposition, for the following intuitive reasons: **(1)** it is itself a transposition or **(2)** $\mathrm{Sgn}(\beta) \mathrm{Sgn}(\beta^{-1})=\mathrm{Sgn}(\beta \beta^{-1})=1$ and $\mathrm{Sgn}(\tau)=-1$ whenever $\tau$ is a transposition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easiest proof. Take the sign function

$$\mbox{sgn}:S_n\to\{-1,1\}$$
$$\mbox{sgn}(a_1\cdots a_n)=(-1)^n\mbox{ for } a_i=\mbox{ transpositions}$$

It can be proved that this is a well defined function and it is a group homomorphism (with integer multiplication on the right side), i.e.

$$\mbox{sgn}(ab)=\mbox{sgn}(a)\mbox{sgn}(b)$$

In particular $\mbox{sgn}(a^{-1})=\mbox{sgn}(a)^{-1}$, the simple property of any group homomorphism.

Therefore

$$\mbox{sgn}(\beta\alpha\beta^{-1})=\mbox{sgn}(\beta)\mbox{sgn}(\alpha)\mbox{sgn}(\beta)^{-1}=\mbox{sgn}(\beta)\mbox{sgn}(\beta)^{-1}\mbox{sgn}(\alpha)=\mbox{sgn}(\alpha)$$

The second equality makes sense, because multiplication in $\{-1,1\}$ is commutative.

Comment: Here's how I solved it.
$\beta\alpha$ is even.
Note: $\beta^{-1}=\alpha$

Observe: 
If $\beta$ is even, then $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is even. $\alpha$ is even.

If  $\beta$ is odd, then $\beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ is odd. $\alpha$ is odd.

Comment: @Mathematicing $\beta^{-1}=\alpha$? Why would you have that? That's definitely not true. What is true howeve is that $\beta^{-1}$ is even if and only if $\beta$ is even. And then your reasoning is correct.